# How can you check if a Rails rich_text_field (Action Text) is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

I can't seem to find this anywhere - the console shows the field as `nil` but in reality action text is storing the content which could be 'blank'.

MyModel.rich_text_field.nil? returns false regardless if the actual content is blank or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if your model field is blank with:

```
MyModel.rich_text_field.blank?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up handling validations for Action Text fields to determine if they were empty.

in my posts_controller I made sure to have  `if @post.save` within the respond_to block.

```
  # POST /posts or /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Post was successfully created."
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in my Post model I added an attribute accessor with custom validations.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  
  attr_accessor :body
  
  # Action Text, this attribute doesn't actually exist in the Post model
  # it exists in the action_text_rich_texts table                  
  has_rich_text :body

  # custom validation (Note the singular validate, not the pluralized validations)
  validate :post_body_cant_be_empty


  # custom model validation to ensure the post body that Action Text uses is not empty
   def post_body_cant_be_empty 
      if self.body.blank?
        self.errors.add(:body, "can't be empty") 
    end   
  end

end
```

now the custom validation will be run to check if the Action Text post body is empty and if it is an error will be displayed to the user when the form is submitted.